# Change environment variables in debian/rules according to debian/control targets

Tags: packaging, environment-variables

I have this package `mypackage` which is already bundled for Ubuntu. For setting the compiler, `debian/rules` contains

```
DEB_CONFIGURE_SCRIPT_ENV += CC=gcc
```

I would now like to extend the package in that I would like to add more targets in `debian/control`, namely `libmypackage-openmpi`, `libmypackage-mpich2` and so forth. The only thing that would theoretically need changing in `debian/rules` is the compiler line above;

```
DEB_CONFIGURE_SCRIPT_ENV += CC=mpicc
```

Is there a way in `debian/rules` to `if`-`else` between the build targets and set `DEB_CONFIGURE_SCRIPT_ENV`  dynamically?

If not, what's the appropriate way to deal with this?

Comment: It would be useful if you could say what package it is. The best way to do it varies by package. You can also look at the existing packages in the archive that do this: `hdf5`, `yorick`, `netpipe`. They all take a fairly old manual style, doing everything explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm getting into the details of debhelper vs. cdbs vs. dh right now, and it seems indeed that cdbs isn't going to get me very far here.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer, Could you update this post?

Comment: @user.dz Update to do what exactly?

Comment: @NicoSchlömer, I thought you already  got a working solution from those packages mentioned by tumbleweed.

Answer (score 1):

- The regular `debian/rules` file runs only 1 cycle.
- Your case seems to require additional cycles (seems 3), here the official tutorial with example for 2 build cycles.

  [Debian Wiki: PkgSplit](https://wiki.debian.org/PkgSplit), removed here [its history](https://wiki.debian.org/PkgSplit?action=info). It is seems outdated.
- You could check more real examples (as mentioned by tumbleweed):

  1. search for ".*-mpi" or `.*-openmpi`

     ```
     apt-cache search --names-only ".*-mpi"
     ```
  2. then download source

     ```
     apt source <packagename>
     ```

  Or you can check online:

  1. Search for [`mpi` through *descriptions*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=all&keywords=mpi) on https://packages.ubuntu.com/ .
  2. Peak one from last suite, example [mrbayes-mpi](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/mrbayes-mpi). Usually, packages are suffixed with used compiler or critical options.
  3. Follow [download source package link](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/hirsute/mrbayes).
  4. Either download *debian* archive or check [its Debian Package Source Repository (Browsable)](https://salsa.debian.org/med-team/mrbayes) on upstream Debian/Ubuntu/External site.
  5. Check `control`, `*.install` files and most important `rules` file.

  Here the multi-cycles build essential part:

  ```
  override_dh_auto_configure:
    dh_auto_configure -- --with-beagle=/usr --enable-mpi=yes --enable-debug=yes

  override_dh_auto_build:
    # build mb-mpi (from initial config)
    LIBS="-Wl,--as-needed" dh_auto_build
    mv src/mb ./mb-mpi
    # Now - build mb
    ( cd src ; make clean )
    dh_auto_configure -- --with-beagle=/usr --enable-mpi=no --enable-debug=yes
    LIBS="-Wl,--as-needed" dh_auto_build
    mv src/mb .
  ```

  It overrides the default and used 2 cycles of (dh_auto_configure & dh_auto_build) then store them with different names.

Comment: you link is sadly a dead link. ;-(

Comment: Hi @christianparpart  , I updated the answer and added an example, so it will be self-explained.