# Is it possible to create several debian packages with different names from one sources adding specific option

Tags: deb, packaging

I created debian packages using debuild.

One by command with variable for one target type:

```
debuild --set-envvar=TARGET=S_SS -b -us -uc -aarm64
```

and another one for another one:

```
debuild --set-envvar=TARGET=S_TT -b -us -uc -aarm64
```

This variable is used in Makefile.

Result of debuild compilation is the *.deb with the same package name for both cases. Is it possible to set a specific package name or path to folder with the files that are necessary for compilation (I mean control, changelog, etc.) different from default "debian"?

Answer (score 0):

Well, `debian/control` supports variable substitutions.

The cleanest options I could think of:

1. (Dynamic) Change the **binary** package names to include your `${variable}`  in `debian/control` then set `debian/rules` to pass the variable to directly using `-V` or by adding it to `debian/substvars`

   Ref: Debian Policy [4.10. Variable substitutions: debian/substvars](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#variable-substitutions-debian-substvars) & [5.2. Source package control files – debian/control](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#source-package-control-files-debian-control)
2. (Static) Make `debian/rules` do multiple configure/build cycles and generate split binary packages. In this case, `debian/control` will have both packages pre-declared and split build files using `debian/<packagename>.install`

   Ref: [Change environment variables in debian/rules according to debian/control targets](https://askubuntu.com/a/908351/26246) (my answer for another related case)